# Create cloned numbered forms dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where only one form appears. This form is:

```
<div style="display: none" class="article_properties">
    <form id="article_properties_form">
        <p>Page Number</p>
        <p id="pageNumber"></p>
        <p>Subtitle</p>
        <input type="text">

        <p>Text</p>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
    </form>
    <div id="addOne" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange; border-radius: 50%">
        <p style="text-align: center; line-height: 25px">+</p>
    </div>
</div> <!--End of article properties div-->
```

When the user clicks the #addOne div, a clone of that form is made. BUT, this form is technically not the same form, because it will have one small detail that will make it uniquely different. This detail is the page number. Every time the #addOne div is clicked, the page number becomes one less. The page number is chosen by the user prior to seeing this current page. For example, let's say the user picks 10 pages. The first form's page number will be 10, the next form when the user clicks the #addOne div it'll be 9 and so on. The first form will always stay at 10 and the second form will always stay at 9, the third form will always stay at 8 and so on.

**Here's my current script:**

```
<script>
    var numPages; //Global var: number of pages user wants

    $('#addOne').click(function() {
        $('#pageNumber').text(numPages);
        numPages--;
        var articlePropsTemplate = $('#article_properties_form').clone();
        $('#article_properties_form').append(articlePropsTemplate);
    });
</script>
```

My current code is producing very weird results. When I click on the #addOne div, the form is being duplicated multiple times instead of once, and the number of pages is not being shown correctly in a logical countdown order. **This form never refreshes and all information is relayed through Ajax.**

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dzgg8m6/6/

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with the minimum code that displays your problem?

Comment: Btw, you haven't initialized your `numPages` variable (it should be `var numPages = 0`). Therefore, `numPages--` will be `undefined - 1`, which will produce `NaN`.

Comment: @madalinivascu Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9dzgg8m6/6/

Comment: @WilliamMartins I didn't include the whole code, but the numPages variable is defined by the user prior to seeing this page.

Comment: I foresee an issue with $(id_selector).clone(). The first time its good the second time your getting multiple elements back for with the same ID.

Comment: You will have invalid html here after you clone the form you will have multiple form with same ID, better use class instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your form :

```
<div class="article_properties">
    <form id="article_properties_form">
        <div class="form-body">//add a class to wrap the elements for cloning
            <p>Page Number</p><p class="pageNumber"></p>//change the id to class
            <p>Subtitle</p>
            <input type="text">

            <p>Text</p>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit/Update">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="addOne" style="width: 25px; height: 25px; background-color: orange; border-radius: 50%"><p style="text-align: center; line-height: 25px">+</p></div>

</div> <!--End of article properties div-->
```

and your js

```
var numPages = 10; 
$('.pageNumber').text(numPages);//add then number for the first element

$('#addOne').click(function()
{

    numPages--;
    var articlePropsTemplate = $('.form-body:last').clone();//clone the last wrapped elements
    $('#article_properties_form').append(articlePropsTemplate);
    $('.pageNumber:last').text(numPages);//append the number after it was placed on the page
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0738u576/

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for explaining each step :)

Comment: Please put your explanation outside the code. It will increase quality of your answer.